# Use php to determine whether the current user Likes a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to Facebook APIs and have to do something which seems to me like it should be fairly simple, but there are so many ways to turn I'm looking for someone who knows the terrain to point me in the right direction.  (I may already be pointed in it, but I'm not having success so I'm asking for help.)

I have a client website which has the Like button on certain pages (along with much other content of course).  That is already implemented using an iframe tag, but I can do it a different way if need be.

What is not implemented and needs to be is that if the visitor has Liked that page, I want to show one block of content, and if he hasn't I want to show a different block.  Most of the page would be identical, so I can't redirect or change the URL to accomplish this.  Nor can I prompt the user for permission.  I have to silently determine whether the visitor Likes the page he's currently on.

Ideally, what I'd like is a php function that will return a boolean whether the visitor likes the current URL or not.  Here it is in pseudocode:

```
function VisitorLikesPageInFacebook($url) {
    # $url = the URL to this page (NOT a Facebook page)
    # if visitor is not logged into Facebook, return false
    # if visitor is logged into Facebook and likes $url, return true
    # if visitor is logged into Facebook and does not like $url, return false
    # if anything else happens, return false
}
```

Can this be done using php?  Do I need the Facebook PHP SDK?  What settings do I need to have in my Facebook app, or better is there any possible way I can do this without creating a Facebook app?  I've tried using $facebook->getUser() but it returns 0 unless I first go to the $facebook->getLoginUrl() address and give permission, which I can't expect visitors to the client site to do.  I've tried $facebook->getSignedRequest() but it returns NULL.  Is there a setting in my Facebook app that I need to set, or some other call I need to make first?  Will I or my client need to have https to give the Facebook app a secure location?

The other piece of this puzzle is that I want the page to refresh when the Like button on it is clicked, and presumably when it does the return value of the above function will change.  For that I assume I'll need to use the JavaScript SDK and subscribe to the Like event.  Is that right?  (My fallback approach, if I can't do what I need to via php, is to use the JavaScript SDK, subscribe to the Like event, and set or unset a cookie depending on whether he Liked or Unliked.  Then read the cookie with php.  JavaScript is nowhere near as familiar to me as php, so I'll avoid it except where required.)

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very happy!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pageID= 'YOURID';  // Used below to fetch


$config = array(
'appID' => 'UR_ID',
'secret' => 'UR_SECRET',
'allowSignedRequest' => false,
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

?>
<html>
<head><title>FB TEST</title></head>
<body>

<?php

if($user_id)

try {
    $user_like = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/likes/'.$pageID,'GET');
    if(!$user_like){
        echo 'User doesnt like';

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    echo 'Please auth us <a href="' . $login_url . '">here.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```